# How to change a dictionary's key

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I've already searched for that this question before but as of not it hasn't helped me at all. So I want to find out how to  change the school subjects after getting this line displayed on my screen '`Console.WriteLine("Lesson 1 " + Info["Lesson 1"] + " Lesson 2 " + Info["Lesson 2"] + " Lessson 3 " + Info["Lesson 3"] + " Lesson 4 " + Info["Lesson 4"] + " Lesson 5 " + Info["Lesson 5"]);`' I want to change the school's subect when I approve it from this line of code:
'

```
public static bool UsersAnswer()
        {
            string message = "Do you want to change anything?";
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            string answer = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            if (answer != "y")
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

but the problem is that I don't know how to do it. So this is my whole program. I would like to ask a user if he wants to change the subject, but I think it is something bound with Dictionary

Here's my whole code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("He's info that will show up after filling");
            var Info = Schedule();
            Console.WriteLine("Lesson 1 " + Info["Lesson 1"] + " Lesson 2 " + Info["Lesson 2"] + " Lessson 3 " + Info["Lesson 3"] + " Lesson 4 " + Info["Lesson 4"] + " Lesson 5 " + Info["Lesson 5"]);
            bool Agrement = true;
            while (Agrement)
            {
                Agrement = UsersAnswer();
                Console.WriteLine("What would you like to change?");

             
            }

        }
        public static Dictionary<string, string> Schedule()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> Schedule = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Schedule.Add("Lesson 1", Console.ReadLine());
            Schedule.Add("Lesson 2", Console.ReadLine());
            Schedule.Add("Lesson 3", Console.ReadLine());
            Schedule.Add("Lesson 4", Console.ReadLine());
            Schedule.Add("Lesson 5", Console.ReadLine());




            return Schedule;
        }
        public static bool UsersAnswer()
        {
            string message = "Do you want to change anything?";
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            string answer = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            if (answer != "y")
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

'

Comment: You can't. You have to add new key and remove old key.

Comment: you shouldn't this can cause problems with the internal buckets.

Comment: if it is changeable, it doesn't seem to be a very good key to work with

Comment: @Danil you don't change keys. In a Dictionary you update values, not keys. Either you are using it incorrectly, or perhaps it's the wrong data structure to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Info variable holds a reference to the Dictionary created by the Schedule function.

So you can simply add more questions to the user in the while loop and set the new value at the end like this:

```
Agrement = UsersAnswer();
Console.WriteLine("What would you like to change (1-5)?");
string subjectToChange = Console.ReadLine();
string key = "Lesson " + subjectToChange;
Console.WriteLine("New subject for " + key + ":");
string newValue = Console.ReadLine();
Info[key] = newValue;
```

If you want to display the current content of the dictionary in each iteration, simply move the Info output from outside the loop to inside:

```
Console.WriteLine("Lesson 1 " + Info["Lesson 1"] + " Lesson 2 " + Info["Lesson 2"] + " Lessson 3 " + Info["Lesson 3"] + " Lesson 4 " + Info["Lesson 4"] + " Lesson 5 " + Info["Lesson 5"]);
Agrement = UsersAnswer();
.....
```

In the Console.ReadLine() function returns a string so there is no need to convert the result in the UsersAnswer. Additionaly you can return the ReadLine() result to the caller. Then you can check the result directly in the while loop.

And for better readability you can write separate functions for the different questions.
The result can look like this (you must add your Schedule function):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("He's info that will show up after filling");
    var Info = Schedule();
    WriteInfo(Info);
    while (UserWantsChange() == "y")
    {
        var keyToChange = WhatShouldChanged();
        Info[keyToChange] = GetNewValueFor(keyToChange);
        WriteInfo(Info);
    }

}

public static void WriteInfo(Dictionary<string, string> info)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Lesson 1 " + info["Lesson 1"] + " Lesson 2 " + info["Lesson 2"] + " Lesson 3 " + info["Lesson 3"] + " Lesson 4 " + info["Lesson 4"] + " Lesson 5 " + info["Lesson 5"]);
}

public static string UserWantsChange()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to change anything (y)?");
    return Console.ReadLine();
}

public static string WhatShouldChanged()
{
    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to change (1-5)?");
    string subjectToChange = Console.ReadLine();
    return "Lesson " + subjectToChange;
}

public static string GetNewValueFor(string lesson)
{
    Console.WriteLine("New subject for " + lesson + ":");
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

At last you can put the whole behaviour in a separate class and call it from the main function (as an exercise).

Answer (score -1):

**to update key, you have to remove it, then simply add new key**

```
_schedule.Remove(key);
_schedule.Add(key, "value");
```

you going to have to sort out how to access the dictionary from you methods

```
Dictionary<string, string> _schedule;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _schedule =  new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

```
_schedule[key] = "new value"
```

```
_schedule["Lesson 1"] = "example text change to user imput"
```

Comment: but what if I want to use a method called Schedule( ) instead of declaring Dictionary out side of the static method?

Comment: Well, you can complain about it @Seabizkit but would you see it as an optimal way to change what the OP wants. If a key is changeable, would that indicate that the datastructure isn't optimal for the desired usage? Sure this is an improvement that could be made, it could be `Lazy<>` to create it exactly once, or there could be other improvements made...

Comment: there's no problem with getting the dictionary by calling a static method like that.

Comment: @juharr what u said but appearly i dont understand.lol

Comment: omg i give up...its agreed "there's no problem with getting the dictionary by calling a static method like that." is the real issue but yet marked down 4 times lol, which is what mine is trying to show.

Comment: @Seabizkit I'm sorry but you make a false assertion that would definitely confuse a newcomer. There's no indication in the question that he thinks he is using shared state but isn't

Comment: how is he going to maintain the dic, if its life scope is not within the scope which is presented. every time UsersAnswer is called get a new dictionary overriding any changes made........., thats not even the q, the question is how to change the key, you remove and add, its not not really changing its just removing and adding. but i digress

Comment: That's a fair point. However, in neither the question nor your answer does he access the dictionary in `UserAnswer`. Maybe explain why you hoisted the scope of the dictionary or show a `UserAnswer` implementation that uses the shared state

Comment: aka i don't see it being passed.... so how did he get access to it....... in UsersAnswer but that not even the q

Comment: @AluanHaddad because, of the main loop....but yes he could pass it in, but again nothing to do with actual q

Comment: I'm not trying to be normative, I'm just trying to understand. Maybe the problem is the question itself but I feel more confused after reading the answer. Why don't you add an example of code that leverages the shared field.

Comment: @AluanHaddad re-ordered... so the focus is put on the q and not the rest of the programming

Comment: @Seabizkit where should I put these lines of code? _schedule[key] = "new value"
_schedule["Lesson 1"] = "example text change to user imput"

Comment: @Danil and that is what i was trying to explain your issue is more about getting access to what you want to modify and currently you have no way of accessing it. You have two options... but really that a separate question. The answer to this one is: you remove old key and add new key.

Comment: You are missing the `static` modifier on your dictionary declaration though